# Getting last and next db-record by date in MySQL-Table?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I've got a certain question related to a blog, which I am developing in OOP (PHP) right now. All blogposts are stored in a MySQL-table.

In the app you can read a specific post by giving the id of the post via GET-parameter. So like `http://example.com/?id=2`. Under the blogpost I want to show to navigation links like "previous" and "next", to see the next and previous blogpost ordered by date relative to the post the user is reading now. So what I need is the id of the next and the previous record in the mysql-table by date.

How to solve this? Is there any way to solve this in SQL, or do I have to get all records with php and then do some checks to determine if this is the last or next one?

Just a note: I don't want to fetch the last and next posts by id, but by date to get the id of them.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of very recent [How to find prev and next id record from table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486778/how-to-find-prev-and-next-id-record-from-table)

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: While similar, that's not an exact duplicate because in that question the field to search by was a PK which is guaranteed to be unique. That's not necessarily the case here.

Comment: @Mark with non-unique values you couldn't move to the next record with same value using your queries.

Comment: @Col Shrapnel: Yes I know, and I mentioned that in my answer. For the more advanced case see my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366777/forward-back-records-in-mysql-with-the-same-data-in-the-primary/3366957#3366957 where I handle this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the newest record older than a certain date:

```
SELECT id
FROM yourtable
WHERE date < '2010-08-15 14:07:12'
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Or the oldest record newer than a certain date:

```
SELECT id
FROM yourtable
WHERE date > '2010-08-15 14:07:12'
ORDER BY date 
LIMIT 1
```

Make sure that the date column is indexed.

This works fine if `date` is unique, but if you have two records with exactly the same date and use next repeatedly this could skip over one of the records. To solve this you could use a tie-breaker column such that (date, tie-breaker) is always unique. You could for example use the primary key as a tie-breaker.

See my answer to this question to see how to do this:

- [Forward Back Records in MySQL with the same DATA in the primary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366777/forward-back-records-in-mysql-with-the-same-data-in-the-primary)

Comment: Does this work, when the table-coloums storing the date are of type "datetime" and not something like unix-timestamp?

Comment: Since I think, that there will never be two records with the same date. I don't have to consider that, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the next id:

SELECT TOP 1 id FROM blogposts WHERE blogdate > $given_date_of_actual_blogpost$ ORDER BY blogdate

the previous id:

SELECT TOP 1 id FROM blogposts WHERE blogdate < $given_date_of_actual_blogpost$ ORDER BY blogdate DESC

Comment: The TOP syntax doesn't work in MySQL. That works in for example SQL Server.

Comment: What does `TOP 1` mean? Is it the same like `LIMIT 1` in the end of the query?

Comment: ah sorry ;) im from the MS Sql World. Of course it s LIMIT 1 for MySql